# Find the package a program is installed with

Tags: package-management, dpkg, uninstall

I installed a software called TopSpin 4.0.7 that I need to purge to reinstall. I however can't uninstall it via

```
sudo apt remove
```

or

```
sudo apt --purge remove
```

because I don't know the true name of the TopSpin 4.0.7 program. Where can I find it's proper name so I can fully uninstall it?

Comment: Looks like you did not install TopSpin from a deb package, so you might be barking up the wrong tree -- APT can only remove software what was installed using deb packages. APT has never heard of snap, pip, flatpack, appimage, tarball, or any of the other ways that you likely installed TopSpin. There's a good chance that the original download is still in your Downloads directory - open it and look for a README file with instructions on how to install and uninstall this non-Ubuntu software.

Comment: @user535733  I found it's an rpm based package meant for CentosOS. The user manaul is pretty sparce on install and unistall details. I did check via programs running on the system and it is simply listed as "topspin" so I guess the question is now how to remove rpm packages on ubuntu. As for install all I did was run <br/>  [bash ./topspin-4.0.7-linux.sh] <br/> and follow the prompted windows from there.

Comment: Take a look at that shell file: topspin-4.0.7-linux.sh . It will have the details of what it installed where. One option is to go through it, line-by-line, and deleted what it installed. Alternately, maybe whomever wrote it included an uninstall option. Only way to find out is to look at the file.

Comment: @user535733 Ok ill try it out, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The following will assume you know the command that executes it, but I'll use `ls` as an example.

I find out where `ls` is actually located

```
guiverc@d960-ubu2:~/Pictures$   whereis ls
ls: /bin/ls /usr/share/man/man1/ls.1.gz
```

Now I know where that, I can ask the package management system to give me a package name

```
guiverc@d960-ubu2:~/Pictures$   dpkg -S /bin/ls
coreutils: /bin/ls
```

Now I know the package name, to remove it I could

```
$ sudo apt remove coreutils
```

Alas I didn't do that; I need it.

If you only access a program through menus, you didn't tell us what release/desktop you are using, but on some you can click & get details very easily, others you can view xml (formatted text files) and see programs run by menus, or you could just start it & `htop` or `ps` to look for the running program to get it's name. In your case with you knowing the name, it may be called something like topspin, so I'd type `tops` at a command prompt, and hit  to see if it auto-completes to the executable name, then you can use the two aforementioned commands.

The above assumes it was deb/apt (package management system) installed.  If @user53733 is correct and you installed it another way; the method differs.

`snap list` will list your snaps, where you can `snap remove <snappackage>` if installed as a snap.

If installed from source; follow the uninstall instructions, or do the reverse of how you installed it (if there is no uninstall directions; though this assumes more knowledge/understanding of procedure and should probably be skipped if not understood)

Comment: Sorry Ubuntu 18.04 LTS, GNOME 3.28.2, and I think I found the issue it's a rpm based package meant for CentosOS. The user manaul is pretty sparce on install and unistall details. I did check via programs running on the system and it is simply listed as "topspin" so I guess the question is now how to remove rpm packages on ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

Enter the topspin folder，there is a folder named "uninstall". Enter it and  run all uninstall files named like `uninstall-topspin.sh`.